# R Data Rearrange

Tags: r

Please let me know 'R code' that could rearrange data from

```
AA 100 NA
BB 200 300
CC 300 NA
DD 100 400
```

to

```
AA 100 0   0   0
BB 0   200 300 0
CC 0   0   300 0
DD 100 0   0   400
```

OR

```
   100 200 300 400
AA 1   0   0   0
BB 0   1   1   0
CC 0   0   1   0
DD 1   0   0   1
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269) and to know what you've tried so far.

Comment: If your data are in a data.frame named `df`, then `table(data.frame(df[,1], unlist(df[,-1])))` will do the trick.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien  make that an answer?  myDF <- 
 data.frame(
  V1 = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD") ,
  V2 = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 100L) , 
  V3 = c(NA, 300L, NA, 400L)
 )

table(data.frame(myDF[,1], unlist(myDF[,-1])))

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I like your method a lot more.  Please go ahead and post that as an answer

Comment: @AnthonyDamico and Ricardo -- OK, just posted it. Feel free to edit/add explanation to my answer if you like -- I thought it a bit opaque without any explanation, and was feeling a bit lazy myself...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved problem. I'm not good at R code now. But I'll try it.

Answer (score 6):

```
df <- read.table(text = "AA 100 NA
BB 200 300
CC 300 NA
DD 100 400")

table(data.frame(letters = df[,1], numbers = unlist(df[,-1])))
#        numbers
# letters 100 200 300 400
#      AA   1   0   0   0
#      BB   0   1   1   0
#      CC   0   0   1   0
#      DD   1   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# SAMPLE DATA
myDF <- structure(list(V2 = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 100L), V3 = c(NA, 300L, NA, 400L)), .Names = c("V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"))
```

Assuming `myDf` is your original data frame

```
# create columns sequence
Columns <- seq(100, 400, by=100)

newMat <- sapply(Columns, function(c) rowSums(c==myDF, na.rm=T))

# assign names
colnames(newMat) <- Columns

newMat  
#      100 200 300 400
#   AA   1   0   0   0
#   BB   0   1   1   0
#   CC   0   0   1   0
#   DD   1   0   0   1
```

---

#### Explanation:

`c == myDF` gives a matrix of TRUE/FALSE values. 
  If you perform arithmetic on T/F, they are treated as 1/0
  Thus, we can take the `rowSum()` for each row AA, BB, etc. 
    which will tell us how many times each row is equal to c.

  We use `sapply` to iterate over each column value, 100, 200, etc. 
    `lapply` returns for us a list 
    `sapply`, takes that list and simplifies it into a nice matrix.

we then clean up the names to make things pretty.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values, one could also use the reshape2 package:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "AA 100 NA
 BB 200 300
 CC 300 NA
 DD 100 400")

library(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(DF, id = "V1")

dcast(dfm, V1 ~ factor(value), fill = 0)[, -6]
  V1 100 200 300 400
1 AA 100   0   0   0
2 BB   0 200 300   0
3 CC   0   0 300   0
4 DD 100   0   0 400
```

The last column in dcast() is removed because NA is a value in dfm$value and takes up the last column in the cast data frame.